# Excel file failed to open after downloading via VBA code from SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am downloading excel file using below VBA code found on web, but after downloading when try to open the file getting the error - excel cannot open the file because the file format is invalid ..."

This problem is only with files downloaded using below code, if I download directly it's working fine

I am using office 365

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
    "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
        szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Sub download_file()
    Dim downloadStatus As Long
    Dim url As String, destinationFile_local As String

    url = "http://sp2019/library/test.xlsx"
    
    destinationFile_local = "C:\test.xlsx"
    downloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, destinationFile_local, 0, 0)

    If downloadStatus = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Download successfully"
    Else
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("http://sp2019/library/test.xlsx")` should work fine here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it will but I want to download the file. In fact number of files that's why using VBA code

Comment: If you open the "invalid" file with a text editor does it contain any useful information (is it HTML for example?)

Answer (score 1):

I have a fix, or at least a workaround, although I can't explain exactly why it works.  Background information: I use URLDownloadToFile in a database containing linked SharePoint lists. The sub in question creates a recordset using SQL against a linked SharePoint list residing on the same site as the files I want to download, and if the record count of the recordset is greater than 0, downloads a file.  This all works well.

In the course of some recent testing to track down an issue, I created a sub that called the same URLDownloadToFile routine to download the same file, but without previously creating a recordset.  Whenever I ran the sub, the file that ended up in the destination folder would be 194 KB, and contain HTML.

Through trial and error, I found that as long as I created a recordset using the linked list before I ran the file download code, it worked fine, and continues to work fine even if I comment out the code containing the recordset creation, as long as I keep the database open. Essentially, you need to do something to open a connection to the SharePoint site before you run URLDownloadToFile.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely open the file with URL path:

https://SITE//PATH/File.extension

The path might be tricky, I advice you to open to excel file online then click on Viewwing : "Open in Desktop App"

Then click on the Excel Desktop App > File > Info Copy File Path
It's a very reliable source of sharepoint URL, and you can absolutely use it.

Answer (score 0):

The URLDownloadToFile function didn't work for me. It downloaded some html code inestead of the Excel file

For Excel files only, I used the Excel.Application object to open the file in the background and then save it in a local folder:

```
Public Sub DownloadExcelFileFromSharepoint(ByVal SharepointFileRoute As String, ByVal TargetDestinationFile As String)
    'No neccesary reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library, using late binding

    Dim oExcelApplication As Object 'Excel.Application
    Dim oExcelWorkbook As Object 'Excel.Workbook

    Set oExcelApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oExcelWorkbook = oExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(SharepointFileRoute, ReadOnly:=True)

    ' Don't display alerts on saving, so if TargetDestinationFile exists will be overwrited
    oExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcelWorkbook.SaveAs TargetDestinationFile
    oExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = True

    oExcelWorkbook.Close
    Set oExcelWorkbook = Nothing
    
    oExcelApplication.Quit
    Set oExcelApplication = Nothing
End Sub
```

Getting the correct URL was not obvious for me. Just copying the Sharepoint's URL while the file is opened in the browser and use it with this funcion won't work. I had to open the file in Excel with the open file dialog, write the shareponit folder and navigate to the file subfolder. I got something like this :

```
https://michelingroup.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/Shared documents/TestFile.xlsx
```