# Download Excel file from Sharepoint, Save to Desktop

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to download an excel file stored in sharepoint (no unc path available) to my desktop.

This code below seems to work and create "CST.xlsx" but I get an error msg:

[image]

**Notes:**
Url for excel file is taken directly from the web address bar and everthing after ".xlsx" is removed.

**Code:**

```
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
    
    Function DownloadFileFromWeb(strURL As String, strSavePath As String) As Long
        ' strSavePath includes filename
        DownloadFileFromWeb = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    End Function
    
    Sub download()
    
    Call DownloadFileFromWeb("url.xlsx", "Desktop\download\CST.xlsx")
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Open the file in Excel directly from the URL and save it to the desktop.

Comment: But the file is updated in sharepoint by other users. I need the latest file downloaded . Would be nice to do that with a vba script.

Comment: If you open the file in Excel why wouldn't that be the latest version?  You can perform those two steps (open/save) using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298459/excel-file-failed-to-open-after-downloading-via-vba-code-from-sharepoint/72365779#72365779) about the same problem for a workaround.